# Android: compatibility issues when publishing

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

I published an application at Android market but the Android market is stating that my application is not compatible with most of the devices. It gave me a list of at least 7 to 9 devices with which my application is not compatible with. ALTHOUGH I have tried my application with some of the devices that are mentioned in the uncompatible devices list and it worked fine there.. Does anyone has a clue about what could be the issue. ??

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your manifest for things that limit the device range - screen size, openGL requirements, minSDK version... The publisher has at the bottom of the details area an area that shows what devices you can filter, make sure you didn't invert it or something (if you can do that.)

Comment: I have mentioned minsdk as 7. is that causing problem. is there any tool that I can use to check the compatibility of my application with different devices?

Comment: You can use the emulator with any devices using API 7 or higher. I believe that is 2.1. What is the message android market gives you? (you said it wasn't reaching many devices?)